# Linq: Add non-existing itemList to database by checking (not Id) but other 'multiple' properties

Tags: c#, linq

I can add a missing list to database as below by checking if Ids already exist:

```
var newIDs = ObjsList.Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
var existingDBObjs = db.Objs.Where(r => newIDs.Contains(r.ObjsId)).ToList();
var missingOrNewObjs = newsList.Where(r => !existingDBObjs.Select(c => c.ObjsId).Equals(r.ObjsId)).ToList();
db.Objs.AddRange(missingOrNewObjs);
```

but how do I add non-existing items to database by checking (not Id) but other 'multiple' properties (using minimum db calls)?

e.g. add relationship row to db only if child id AND parent id do not exist in relationship table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type. I would also suggest to use `Join`:

```
var missingOrNewObjs = from newobj in ObjsList
                       join existing in db.Objs
                       on new { newobj.Name, newobj.Number, newobj.Address }
                       equals new { existing.Name, existing.Number, existing.Address } into grpJoin
                       from outerjoin in grpJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where outerjoin == null
                       select newobj;
db.Objs.AddRange(missingOrNewObjs);
```

Comment: this is 'great' any chance of same thing in dot syntax? Thank you

Comment: @ManojSharma: it is possible but it will destroy readability. I always prefer  query or a mixture of query- and method-syntax when it comes to joins.  You need to look at [`Enumerable.GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535047(v=vs.100).aspx)